# How to populate the value of a Text Box based on the value in a Combo Box in MS Access 2007?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have a combo box which is of a lookup type, i.e., I've selected the source to be a column from a table and am storing the selected value in another table. The table which I am looking up has another column and I need the value in this column to be displayed in a text box and each time I change the value in the combo box, I need the corresponding value to be displayed in the text box. How can I do this? What I have done so far is to write a `Select` query that selects the appropriate column based on the combo box's value. Is there a more decent way of doing this? Please help me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the source of the combo box to your 2 fields e.g. `SELECT id, name FROM Customers`
Make sure you set the Column Count property of the combo to 2, accordingly.
Then make you unbound text box source equal to `=MyCombo.Column(1)` (from memory, this Column is zero based).
That's it, zero code required.

Comment: I tried this method. But it works only the first time it is created. When I close and re-open it, the text box, which has been set to `ComboBox.Column(1)` shows `#Name?`. Why is this happening? What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It's nicer to use an event of the combo box e.g. onChange, so when a selection is made the event sets the value of the text box.

```
me!txtTextBox1 = me!cboComboBox1.column(1)
```

That way it will work everytime.

You could also use a button with onClick etc. but the choice is yours (and as mentioned in the previous post, alter the column number based on its row source with 0 being the first.

Comment: Setting an unbound textbox to depend on the combo as illustrated by @iDevlop works every time with no code at all, so it is a better solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question and answers I tried the following, and it seems to work well (so far):

In order to display more than one column of a combobox selection, I have resorted to the following:

Place a textbox over the combobox,
Size it by sampling other fields, so that it covers the text frame of the combobox.
I have purposely have left a small space to the right of the NEW textbox to indicate that it 
    Is NOT part of the combobox.

In the Control Source for the textbox enter the expression below:

```
=[DefaultAcct].[Column](1) & "  " & [DefaultAcct].[Column](2)
```

Then, in the ‘onchange’ event of the combobox, set focus to the textbox.

```
Private Sub DefaultAcct_Change()
    txtConcatenate1.SetFocus   
End Sub
```