# MS Access - If Statement with combo box and textbox

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a combo list box that has 4 values (a,b,c,d). I have a textbox also. I want the textbox to update based on the value selected from the combobox. For example, the textbox has a default value of text. I want to put an if statement somewhere that says if combobox value = b then make the text in the textbox "Yes" else make it "No". I don't know what the if statement should be or where it should go. I'd like to do this without coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate the value of a Text Box based on the value in a Combo Box in MS Access 2007?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422956/how-to-populate-the-value-of-a-text-box-based-on-the-value-in-a-combo-box-in-ms)

Comment: Do you have a combo box or a list box?

Answer (score 1):

Use as ControlSource for the textbox:

```
=IIf([NameOfYourCombobox]="b","Yes","No")
```