# Repeating Text Fields & ComboBox Fields

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word, auto-populate

I would like to have a ComboBox determine the text that appears in another Rich Text Content Control Field.

Additionally, I would like to have a separate set of  Rich Text Content Control Fields that mirror each other.  If you enter "Hello" in one field, "Hello" appears in the other, and vice versa.  So you can change either one, and the other will update.

Is there a way to do this with VBA?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with our without code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423819/7857211) SO article explains it quite well.